# GPS INS navigation

Tags: 3d-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,
I am new with ROS and would like to implement autonomous outdoor navigation using GPS/INS device. I have a differential wheel robot and I can now control it remotely in ROS. Can you give me an idea which pkg to use and how to proceed in order to be able to implement autonomous outdoor navigation using GPS/INS device?

Thx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149106/gps-ins-navigation/) by [fatiba](https://answers.ros.org/users/11351/fatiba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CMobley7](https://answers.ros.org/users/20654/cmobley7/) on 2015-02-26**:
Fatiba,

Any luck on finding applicable packages.

Very Respectfully,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You could use Robot Localization http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization.  There is a tutorial on how to connect with your gps: http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/GPS%20Integration

Matt

---

Originally posted by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) with karma: 90 on 2015-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1